# multiply vector / csr matrix row by "gradient descent" weights in numpy / scipy

Tags: python, numpy, vector, scipy

I have a [csr matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) and my idea is to multiply each row by weights that would be related to order of greatest values in the matrix row. if the row has 5 nonzero values then multiply the biggest value by 5 (normalized), second biggest by 4 etc.

in fact it is inspiration by [WMA in trading](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/071414/whats-difference-between-moving-average-and-weighted-moving-average.asp), so in case of 5 values multiply biggest by 5/(5+4+3..1) (to sum of weights).

is there any optimized algorithm how to do this in numpy or scipy?

Answer (score 0):

I will do something like this:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
M = csr_matrix([2,0,4], dtype=np.float64)
NZ = np.nonzero(M.getrow(0).A[0])[0]
for k,v in enumerate(np.flip(np.argsort(M.getrow(0).A[0][NZ]))):
    M[0,NZ[v]] *= ((len(NZ)-k) / (len(NZ) * (len(NZ) + 1) // 2))
```

Result matrix M is:

```
array([[0.66666667, 0.        , 2.66666667]])
```

## =========================================

Another solution is below but that uses ordering which is what I don't want I realized:

```
x = np.array([3,1,2]) # row of a matrix
s = np.argsort(x)     # indexes representing ordered values (asc order)
s = np.flip(s)        # flipping asc to desc
y = x[s] * [(len(x)-k)/x.sum() for k, v in enumerate(s)] # do the magic
```

y is now:

```
array([1.5       , 0.66666667, 0.16666667])
```

thus same as multiplying: (notice the order is changed)

```
np.array([3,2,1])
```

with weights:

```
np.array([0.5, 0.3333333333333333, 0.16666666666666666])
```

Only problem is, the x must be reordered, since argsort says order of values, but not order of values while keeping the original order of values.

Other solution could use np.fromfunction() or np.vectorize() to call callback over the vector (i needed to know the index of value to do something like 3-index to get the target weight) but for my brain was eaiser the list comprehension for now.